# Firebase Firestore pagination best practice/optimized or no?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know if it is a best practice to do pagination with firebase firestore
I ask because when we retrieve a list (example: product list) firebase returns all the data, and I will take for example the 10 first element. Pagination after pagination, I take a step of 10.
So if that means that at each pagination I retrieve the list again and I find that it is not efficient. We retrieve the list several times.
Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pagination is important considering the daily limit for free tier (50k )

Here is a good read about using startAt() and endAt()
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors

another good resource is this video : https://fireship.io/lessons/firestore-pagination-guide/